# Using Enumerable.Repeat to populate a 2D collection

Tags: c#

I can do this:

```
var o = Enumerable.Repeat((object)null, 5).ToList();
```

To create a `List<object>` with 5 `null`, then I can do this:

```
o[0] = 5;
```

To assign a value and `o[0] == 5` and `o[1] == null` as expected. However, if I do this:

```
var oo = Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Repeat((object)null, 5).ToList(),5).ToList();
```

I create a 2D `List<List<object>>`, but if I do this:

```
var oo[0][0] = 5;
```

Then `oo[0][0] == 5`, but also `oo[1][0] == 5` and `oo[2][0] == 5`. In other words, instead of creating a new 1D `List<object>` and repeating it 5 times, it's repeated the same list. Thinking about it, that does make sense. But the question is, how can I get it to create a new List each time?

I thought this might work:

```
Enumerable.Repeat(new Lazy<List<object>>(() => 
    Enumerable.Repeat((object)null, colCount).ToList()).Value, rowCount).ToList();
```

But it's repeating the same value still.

Now, of course, there are dozens of other ways I can create and populate a 2D List with nulls (nested loops, for example), but I'm wondering if there is a way to make this work with `Repeat`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to do this using `Range` for the outer part:

```
var oo = Enumerable.Range(0,5).Select(i => 
           Enumerable.Repeat((object)null,5).ToList()).ToList();
```

Using `Range` I'm going to iterate other the numbers `0...4` (5 numbers) and for each one `.Select` a new List generated with `Repeat`. So instead of repeating the same list 5 times, it's generating a new list each time.

Comment: I use Range like this all the time as well, especially when it makes sense for `i` to be used in a ctor for testing.

Comment: It would be nice if you included the reason why the other version didn't work. For example, that the same object is repeated 5 times in the previous version, and that a new object is created here in the func closure.

Comment: @TravisJ It's included in the question.

Comment: @Servy "Thinking about it, that does make sense" doesn't exactly get to the why.

Comment: @TravisJ . `instead of creating a new 1D List<object> and repeating it 5 times, it's repeated the same list.  [...] how can I get it to create a new List each time?`  That's exactly the problem; he's repeating the same list, not repeating 5 different lists.

Comment: @Servy - The list is repeated is a symptom. Here is what is happening. It does not explain why it happens.

Comment: @TravisJ What do you mean symptom?  That's the problem.  He's repeating the same list 5 times, not creating 5 new lists.  Are you asking why calling `Repeat` repeats the same object over and over?  That should be obvious given its name.

Comment: @Servy - Your logical fallacy has no bearing here. This is an answer to the question. Ideally, it should provide a reason why this does not have the same pitfall as the problem described. Sure, all answers could just be pure code, but that doesn't really help other users.

Comment: @TravisJ This answer answers the actual question asked in the question.  You seem to be concerned because this answer isn't answering a question that you have with the code in one of the examples in the question, rather than the actual question asked.  If you want to see posts answering the question of why `var query = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<int>(), 5);` doesn't create 5 lists, you can ask that question, but it's not what this question is asking.

Comment: @Servy - I have no qualms with any of the code presented here. You seem to have a bad reputation for misconstruing other people's arguments and then responding to your own view of what was said. All I asked was that instead of providing a simple one line of code answer to a question posed by this same user, they actually include an explanation. You seem more concerned with arguing than actually paying attention to other users.

Comment: "I use Range like this all the time". I did too, until I came across `Repeat` and thought for cases where I just want to initialize a list with all the same value, this is great. Until I ran into this 2D problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you're logtically trying to do is generate objects using a generator function N times, rather than repeat an object N times; write a function that does *that*:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(Func<T> generator, int count)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        yield return generator();
}
```

You can now generate sequences of, for example, empty lists:

```
var list = Generate(() => new List<object>(), 5);
```

Comment: Hmmm...thanks. I quite like that solution. It's less unwieldy than the `Range.Select` solution I had.